# Compare two columns of different files and add new column if it matches

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I would like to compare the first two columns of two files, if matched need to print yes else no.

input.txt

```
123,apple,type1
123,apple,type2
456,orange,type1
6567,kiwi,type2
333,banana,type1
123,apple,type2
```

qualified.txt

```
123,apple,type4
6567,kiwi,type2
```

output.txt

```
123,apple,type1,yes
123,apple,type2,yes
456,orange,type1,no
6567,kiwi,type2,yes
333,banana,type1,no
123,apple,type2,yes
```

I was using the below command for split the data, and then i will add one more column based on the result.

Now the the input.txt has duplicate(1st column) so the below method is not working, also the file size was huge.

Can we get the output.txt in `awk` one liner?

```
comm -2 -3 input.txt qualified.txt
```

Comment: Why the first 2 columns? It looks like the first 2 are always paired so why not just compare 1 of them? If they aren't always paired (e.g. you can have `123,apple` and `9631,apple`) then include that in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR {a[$1 FS $2];next} {print $0 FS (($1 FS $2) in a?"yes":"no")}' qual input
123,apple,type1,yes
123,apple,type2,yes
456,orange,type1,no
6567,kiwi,type2,yes
333,banana,type1,no
123,apple,type2,yes
```

Explained:

```
NR==FNR {                    # for the first file
    a[$1 FS $2];next         # aknowledge the existance of qualified 1st and 2nd field pairs
} 
{
    print $0 FS ($1 FS $2 in a?"yes":"no")        # output input row and "yes" or "no"
}                                                 # depending on whether key found in array a
```

No need to redefine the `OFS` as `$0` isn't modified and doesn't get rebuilt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` logic for this as below. Not sure why do you mention one-liner awk command though.

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR{map[$1]=$2;next} {if($1 in map == 0) {$0=$0FS"no"} else {$0=$0FS"yes"}}1' qualified.txt input.txt

123,apple,type1,yes
123,apple,type2,yes
456,orange,type1,no
6567,kiwi,type2,yes
333,banana,type1,no
123,apple,type2,yes
```

The logic is

- The command `FNR==NR` parses the first file `qualified.txt` and stores the entries in column `1` and `2` in first file with first column being the index.
- Then for each of the line in 2nd file `{if($1 in map == 0) {$0=$0FS"no"} else {$0=$0FS"yes"}}1` the entry in column 1 does not match the array, append the `no` string and `yes` otherwise.
- `-v FS="," -v OFS=","` are for setting input and output field separators

Comment: Not putting a space after `-v` makes your script completely unnecessarily gawk-specific. The array name `seen` is idiomatically used to represent a set, not a mapping. Use `map` or similar instead for clarity if you're creating a map, but I don't see you actually referencing it as a map, just populating it as such so idk...

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the correction, Wish I knew it before :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like all you need is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR{a[$1];next} {print $0, ($1 in a ? "yes" : "no")}' qualified.txt output.txt
```